# I have problem with access to ftp server via bitbucket pipeline

Tags: git, ftp, continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I want deploy my website when I push changes on master.

I tried to follow the guides from bitbucket and other sites but nothing solved my issues.

My .yml file look like that

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo "Pipeline Init"
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_HOST
```

and I got error like that

```
+ git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_HOST
fatal: Can't access remote 'ftp://osienkiewicz:***@192.168.13.69', exiting
```

I have access via web browser to ftp server.

I don't know what I do wrong.

Comment: i think i saw the same tutorial, also doesn't work here .. accessing the FTP works without problems .. :/

Comment: Same problem here :-(

Comment: having the same problem from last week. Anybody got any solutions for this?